# React SPA with oidc-client and client secret

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I'm building a React SPA on top of a ASP.NET Core API and I want to authenticate with OIDC. Grant type is authorization code and the client does have a client secret.

Since we will be using a client secret, the authorization step that involves the secret has to go through a proxy that we control.

Is this doable in a React SPA with oidc-client?

Comment: Consider using an authentication provider like Azure AD.  Here's a [sample application](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-spa-dotnetcore-webapi-obo) doing that.

Comment: I should have mentioned that. The authentication platform (and method) has already been decided. Using Azure AD is not an option, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

If the secret is in the client, it's not a secret. :)

Secrets are for server-server authentication, because the secret is secure on a server (we hope so, anyway) and the API granting access has a whitelist of consumers it's granted access to use the secret.

For a SPA, if you're talking about *allowing an app to use an API*, I believe you're limited to using a CORS whitelist. If you're talking about *a user* accessing the API via the client, then you're looking at access codes and usernames/password.

Comment: Thanks for your input. We are talking about a user accessing the API via the client here.

Comment: The client accesses the API as you say - this happens after sign in completes. You should say why you need to use a client secret. If you are using a server side flow it is standard to use a server side security library rather than oidc-client. However, a client side flow will fit much better with a React architecture.

Comment: We've been told to use a client secret as the authentication platform does not support public clients. So yeah, a server side library would be much better suited. But from what I gather, that won't work well with a React architecture.

Comment: Ah - I understand - and you seem to want the same architecture goals as me. I updated my original answer with further details. My solution is tricky, but I much prefer it over web server side security.

Comment: @nednull _We've been told to use a client secret as the authentication platform does not support public clients_ -- even so, your secret is exposed to _anyone_ in the company that can find it. If any of those APIs are publicly exposed now or in the future, that's a pretty gaping hole in your security.

Comment: @Yatrix if the authentication step involving the secret goes through a proxy that we control, the secret will only be visible to other developers.

Comment: @nednull I'm confused. I thought the client was a React app. If a React app is passing it, it exists on the local machine somewhere, either in the JS bundle or a cookie or storage. Right? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Yatrix I'm talking about keeping the client secret server-side. That way, the step involving the secret is passed through the server application where the secret is applied to the request going to the authentication server. Sorry about the confusion. :)

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM**

You have a blocking issue with the authentication system, or with usability or getting security to an acceptable level. In your case there is no PKCE support.

**PROXYING SOLUTION**

Use oidc-client which will add PKCE parameters and your SPA security supports the latest standards.

The client secret will come into play during the authorization code grant and refresh token grant messages.

Messages can be adapted server side to remove PKCE and use a client secret instead. It is quite a complex solution though and not everyone will like it.

It requires a SameSite cookie issued by the web domain. In my case I used an AWS lambda edge function that runs within a CloudFront content delivery network.

**WHY DO IT THIS WAY?**

In order to fit into an SPA architecture and meet wider goals in areas such as usability, coding model, mobile integration and global web performance. Depends if you feel it is worth the effort.

**LINKS**

- [Architecture Goals](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/08/goal-1-spas/)
- [Design Pattern](https://authguidance.com/2020/07/21/spa-reverse-proxy-based-token-renewal/)
- [Code Sample you can run](https://authguidance.com/2019/04/08/how-to-run-the-react-js-spa/)
- [Online AWS SPA](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/)
- [Proxying details](https://authguidance.com/2019/04/08/web-reverse-proxy-implementation/)